# Confusing Wording in SSH-CONNECT [RFC4254]

Tags: networking, ssh, system, rfc

Find the document here: [SSH-CONNECT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4254#section-5)

In "Opening a Channel" (SSH-CONNECT, 5.1), it is stated that "If the recipient of the SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN message does not support the specified 'channel type', it simply responds with SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE".

Does this mean that ONLY the SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE byte is sent, as was the case for SSH_MSG_REQUEST_FAILURE, or would the message be sent with the "SSH_OPEN_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_TYPE" reason code, with all the same fields as the other failure messages?

Perhaps SSH_OPEN_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_TYPE might just mean that the recipient is unaware that any such 'channel type' exists, where as the statement provided is a response to the event that the recipient KNOWS that said 'channel type' DOES indeed exist, but explicitly does not support it?

Comment: What part of ‘does not support’ don’t you understand?

Comment: @user207421 you obviously do not understand the question